# Taking the Max and Min of a list and calculate the difference in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

Having trouble getting the code to work. I feel like the issue is in the helper function dia1. Just wondering where I made a mistake?

```
append([],L,L). 
append([H|T],L2,[H|L3])  :-  append(T,L2,L3).


dia([H|T],N):-
    dia1(H,T,null,N).

dia1(_,_,N,N).

dia1(H,[H1|T1],_,N):-
    H>H1,
    X is H-H1,
    append(T1,[H1],L1),
    dia1(H,L1,X,N).

dia1(H,[H1|T2],_,N):-
    H=<H1,
    X is H-H1,
    append(T2,[H],L2),
    dia1(H1,L2,X,N).


Example test:
dia( [ 1, 5, 3, 1 ], 4 ) 
True
dia( [ 5, 5, 5 ], 0 ) 
True
```

Comment: Note the difference between `[H, T]` and `[H | T]`.

Comment: oh wow lol thank you! I made the corrections,  but its still not giving me the right result.

Comment: Please update the question with the new version of your code! You can use the "edit" button. Just replace the old code with the new one. Also, please add more tests and show how they behave and how you would like them to behave.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: I am able to get the results true, but when I try to make the input false it gives me an error(Out of local stack).

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the algorithm you are trying to implement. Which variable holds the max of the list? Which holds the min of the list? Where do you compute their difference? I think you should try something simpler first: A predicate that only computes the maximum of a list. Then a separate predicate that only computes the minimum. *Then* you can think about how to compose them.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done shortly :

```
dial([H|T], R) :-
    dial(T, H, H, Min, Max),
    R is Max - Min.

dial([], Min, Max, Min, Max).

dial([H | T], Cur_Min, Cur_Max, Min, Max) :-
    H < Cur_Min
    -> dial(T, H, Cur_Max, Min, Max)
    ;  H > Cur_Max
       -> dial(T, Cur_Min, H, Min, Max)
       ;  dial(T, Cur_Min, Cur_Max, Min, Max).
```

for example :

```
?- dial( [ 1, 5, 3, 1 ], X ) .
X = 4.
```

With library clfpd, we get :

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).


dial([H|T], R) :-
    dial(T, H, H, Min, Max),
    R #= Max - Min.

dial([], Min, Max, Min, Max).

dial([H | T], Cur_Min, Cur_Max, Min, Max) :-
    H #< Cur_Min
    -> dial(T, H, Cur_Max, Min, Max)
    ;  H #> Cur_Max
       -> dial(T, Cur_Min, H, Min, Max)
       ;  dial(T, Cur_Min, Cur_Max, Min, Max).
```

For example :

```
?- dial( [ 1, 5, 3, 1 ], X ) .
X = 4.

?- dial( [ 1, X, 3, 1 ], 4 ) .
X = -1.

?- dial( [ 1, X, 3, Y ], 4 ) .
X = 0,
Y = -1.

?- dial( [ A, B, C, D ], 4 ) .
4+D#=A,
B#=<A+ -1,
D#=<C+ -1,
C#=<B+ -1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yor program is quite messy, and does not gives the correct result. For instance:

```
? - dia([1,5,3,1],A).
A = null
A = -4
A = 2
A = 4
A = 4
A = 2
A = 4
and so on...
```

It shoud give only `A = 4`.

You can simplify your code creating two predicates, for instance `my_maxlist/2` and `my_minlist/2` to get the min and the max of the list and then subtract the values, like this:

```
solve(L,Diff):-
    my_minlist(L,Min),
    my_maxlist(L,Max),
    Diff is Max-Min.

my_minlist([A],A):- !.
my_minlist([H|T],Min):-
    my_minlist_(T,H,Min).

my_maxlist([A],A):- !.
my_maxlist([H|T],Max):-
    my_maxlist_(T,H,Max).

my_minlist_([],Min,Min).
my_minlist_([H|T],CurrentMin,Min):-
    CurrentMin < H, !,
    my_minlist_(T,CurrentMin,Min).
my_minlist_([H|T],_,Min):-
    my_minlist_(T,H,Min).

my_maxlist_([],Min,Min).
my_maxlist_([H|T],CurrentMax,Min):-
    CurrentMax > H, !,
    my_maxlist_(T,CurrentMax,Min).
my_maxlist_([H|T],_,Min):-
    my_maxlist_(T,H,Min).
```

Keep in mind that `min_list/2` and `max_list/2` are part of `library(lists)` in SWI prolog, so already defined and so you can simply write:

```
solve(L,Diff):-
    min_list(L,Min),
    max_list(L,Max),
    Diff is Max-Min.
```

Query (in both cases):

```
?- solve([4,3,1,7],D).
D = 6
```